# Grunt: Dist folder not created after grunt command

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs

I'm new using Grunt and I need some help please. I got to the point when I should have a 'Dist' folder after running the grunt command but nothing is happening. I don't have any errors and everything seems to be fine. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function (grunt) {

 // Time how long tasks take. Can help when optimizing build times
 require('time-grunt')(grunt);

 // Automatically load required Grunt tasks
 require('jit-grunt')(grunt);

 // Define the configuration for all the tasks
 grunt.initConfig({
      pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

// Make sure code styles are up to par and there are no obvious mistakes
jshint: {
  options: {
    jshintrc: '.jshintrc',
    reporter: require('jshint-stylish')
  },
  all: {
    src: [
      'Gruntfile.js',
      'app/scripts/{,*/}*.js'
    ]
  }
},
copy: {
  dist: {
    cwd: 'app',
    src: [ '**','!styles/**/*.css','!scripts/**/*.js' ],
    dest: 'dist',
    expand: true
  },
fonts: {
      files:[
          {
              //for bootstrap fonts
                expand: true,
                dot: true,
                cwd: 'bower_components/bootstrap/dist',
                src: ['fonts/*.*'],
                dest: 'dist'
            }, {
                //for font-awesome
                expand: true,
                dot: true,
                cwd: 'bower_components/font-awesome',
                src: ['fonts/*.*'],
                dest: 'dist'
            }
      ]
    }
 },
clean: {
    build:{
        src: [ 'dist/']
    }
  }
 });
  grunt.registerTask('build', [
   'clean',
  'jshint',
  'copy'
  ]);
  grunt.registerTask('default',['build']);
  };
```

Comment: Can you provide us with the relevant file hierarchy to your project?

Comment: All good. The code it's ok. The problem was that I had the Gruntfile in the wrong folder :/

Answer (score 0):

looks like you missed trailing slash.

try

```
dest: 'dist/'
```